# How do I add an element at a specific index in Javascript set object?

Tags: javascript, set, addition

I tried using `options.splice(index, 0, value);` but it only works for arrays not for set objects. Don't suggest ES6 ways please.

Comment: There is no such way to add at particular index in Set . It always appends the element at the end of the Set Please check this documentaion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add

Comment: What do you mean with *set objects*? Can you show an example of the code that you have and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have ou tried this example: `let mArray=Array.from(mySet);
mArray.splice(1,0,6)
mySet=new Set(mArray);`

Comment: Please add pseudo code what are you trying to achieve. How did you create Set without ES6 syntax. Could you please show us your code?

Comment: A set isn’t ordered though...? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089695/how-can-i-sort-an-es6-set so I don’t think they have indexes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the set to an array, do what you want and convert it back to a set.

```
// Assuming options is a Set
var optionsArray = Array.from(options);
optionsArray.splice(index, 0, value);
options = new Set(optionsArray);
```

---

ES6 even though you don't want it :)

```
// Assuming options is a Set
const optionsArray = [...options];
optionsArray.splice(index, 0, value);
options = new Set(optionsArray);
```