# extract only sort function from code block

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am using the following bookmarklet to sort textarea ascending or descending. It is working as expected.
But I do not need descending sort option and there is no need of arrows like '↑' or '↓'

I am not able to extract the basic sort function from this code.

```
javascript: (
  function() {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('textarea')).map(function(b) {
      var a = document.createElement('div');
      var d = document.createElement('button');
      d.textContent = '↑';
      d.addEventListener('click', function(f) {
        f.preventDefault();
        b.value = Array.from(new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().join('\n')
      });
      var c = document.createElement('button');
      c.textContent = '↓';
      c.addEventListener('click', function(f) {
        f.preventDefault();
        b.value = Array.from(new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().reverse().join('\n')
      });
      a.appendChild(d);
      a.appendChild(c);
      b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b)
    })
  }
)();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it's the call to `.sort()`

Comment: `Array.from(new Set(THE_TEXT.split('\n'))).sort().join('\n')` and the `.sort` is what makes the set sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the bookmarklet code is used to create the buttons.

- If you don't need both sort options, you can remove the 'descending'
  button and rename the other one to just sort.
- If you don't need any button at all, you can remove them so the
  bookmarklet sorts all text areas directly when clicked.

```js
function oneButton() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('textarea')).map(function(b) {
    var a = document.createElement('div');
    var d = document.createElement('button');
    d.textContent = 'Sort';
    d.addEventListener('click', function(f) {
      f.preventDefault();
      b.value = Array.from(new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().join('\n')
    });
    a.appendChild(d);
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b)
  })
}
oneButton() // simulates bookmarklet click

function noButton() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('textarea')).map(function(b) {
    b.value = Array.from(new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().join('\n')
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea>B
A</textarea><button onclick="this.previousSibling.value='B\nA'">Reset</button><br>
<!-- noButton function is inserted, you can save this as bookmarklet -->
<a href="javascript:void Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('textarea')).map(function(b){b.value=Array.from(new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().join('\n')});" onclick="void Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('textarea')).map(function(b){b.value=Array.from(new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().join('\n')});" title="You can save this as bookmarklet">'Sort directly' bookmarklet</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The sort function is `sort()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)).

---

Details:

```
b.value = Array.from(new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().join('\n')
```

This is the section responsible for sorting. Let's explain it:
The code you brought in uses a `set` data ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)) structure, probably to avoid duplication - but it is not always consumed.
In fact you can sort an array with `sort` only:

```
[5, 2, 6, 1].sort() // [1, 2, 5, 6]
```

But I will explain the other parts of this code:

- `Array.from` - accepts the `set`, and turns it into an iterator - so that sort can be run on it. ([See more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33089750/17059718))
- `new Set(b.value.split('\n')))` - Creates a set-type data structure that takes an array. The array consists of `b.value.split('\ n')` which means the contents of the text box, with each row being an element in the array - `n\` in JS is a row drop.

We now have an array of lines that were in the text box, when there are no duplicates since we used the `set`.

- Sort the array using `sort()`.

Now all that remains is to connect the sorted array back to a text string, with a line drop between lines.
We do this with `.join('\n')` which causes the array to be connected to a text string, with a line drop between members.

And now we'll go back to the beginning of the line - `b.value =`, which puts the processed string (after converting to an array with `split`, removing duplicates (`set`), sorting with `sort`, and finally connecting back to a separated string in descending rows with `join`) as the value of the text box. ([See here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp) on setting the value of a text box)

I hope I helped :) If something is not understood write in the comment and I will try to answer.

Links for further expansion:

- [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)